# How to update a nested state properties with e.target.name in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, setstate

I am trying to update the state by using nested property like this:

```js
State = {
  newProperty: {
    name: '',
    description: '',
    guestCount: '',
  }
}
```

I am updating the state like this:

```js
handleOnChangeInput = (e) => {
    let prevState = Object.assign({}, this.state.newProperty)
    let targetName = e.target.name
    preState.targetName  = e.target.value
    this.setState({ newProperty: prevState })
}
```

However, preState is not taking the value of targetName, and instead is looking for the targetName property in the state. I tried different variations like preState.[targetName] and it Still did not work.

Comment: You'r newProperty object has field `name` but you're trying to set `targetname`??

Comment: Your syntax is just off. To use a computed object property, you access the object using array syntax: `obj[computed_property]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a new property, wrap it with square brackets as you showed above but drop the .

Principle is the same with any JSON updating. Here is an example of what the above would do:

```js
state = {
    newProperty: {
        name: '',
        description: '',
        guestCount: '',
    }
}

handleOnChangeInput = (e) => {
        let prevState = Object.assign({}, state.newProperty)
        let targetName = e.name
        prevState[targetName]  = e.value
        state.newProperty = prevState
        console.log(state)
}
```

```html
<input name="name" id="waffles" onchange="handleOnChangeInput(this)"/>
```